# How can I make my cursor synced with the control point during a resize?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, graphics, transform

I am creating an editor.
I would like the basic functions on my objects which are **rotate/resize** and **translate**.

I've managed to do the three of them but the only problem is now my mouse position doesn't follow the control points (the problem gets even worst for the other control points not shown below)..

You'll find below an example for the right middle resize with a rotation angle of 30 degrees with no mouseY position, note that the mouse follows perfectly my control point when the rotation angle equals 0.

Is there a way easily solve this problem, am I going the wrong way?

Here's the jsfiddle link where you can change the rotate angle in the code to see by yourself [JSiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/05fn73rd/16/). (Just click and drag the black control point to resize the object)

```js
//convert value of range amin to amax to the range bmin to bmax;
function imap(value, amin, amax, bmin, bmax)
{
 if ((amax - amin))
  return (value - amin) * (bmax - bmin) / (amax - amin) + bmin;
 return (0);
};

//get mouse coordinates from the SVG element
function getMouse(el, e)
{
  var pt = el.createSVGPoint();
 pt.x = e.clientX;
 pt.y = e.clientY;
 var cursorpt =  pt.matrixTransform(el.getScreenCTM().inverse());
 return({x: cursorpt.x, y: cursorpt.y})
};

var controlPoint = document.getElementById("c"); //My control point element

var mouseX;
var mouseXClicked = 0;
var scaleX = 1;
var scaleY = 1;
var scaleXClicked = 1;
var control = false; // sets if resizeRightMiddle() should be executed
var rectWidth = 100; //is normally tooken with a getBBox() function
var scale = document.getElementById("scale");

function resizeRightMiddle()
{
  //convert difference between original mouse X postion on click and actual X mouse position into a scale factor
 plusX = imap(mouseX - mouseXClicked, 0, rectWidth, 0, 1);
  //add converted scale factor to the original x scale value
 resX = scaleXClicked + plusX;
 scale.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(' + resX + ',' + scaleY + ')');
 scaleX = resX;
}

var svg = document.getElementById("main");
// save Scale and X mouse coordinate on click
svg.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
 var coord = getMouse(svg, e);
 mouseXClicked = coord.x;
 scaleXClicked = scaleX;
});

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
//get mouse coordinates
 var coord = getMouse(svg, e);
 mouseX = coord.x;
// resize if control element has been clicked
 if (control)
  resizeRightMiddle();
});

// desactivate resize
svg.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
 control = false;
});

//activate resize
controlPoint.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
 control = true;
});
```

```css
svg {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg id="main" width="1000" height="300">
 <g transform="translate(66, 56)">
  <g id="rotate" transform-origin="center" transform="rotate(30)">
   <g id="scale">
     <path fill="red" stroke="red" d="M 0 0 L 0 100 L 100 100 L 100 0Z" />
    <rect id="c" fill="black" stroke="black" x=95 y=45 width=10 height=10 />
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code will be a little easier to look over and/or reason about with some better variable names: What are `imap`, `v`, `a...`, `b...`, and `RM`?

Comment: imap is a mapping function to map a value v from one range amin to amax to another range bmin to bmax. RM is the right middle resize function, the main function to resize the shape

Comment: the `transform-origin="center"` renders this invisible in Chrome current version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below calculates how much the mouse moves in the direction of the rectangle's orientation on each mousemove event, instead of from the beginning of the mousedown to the current mousemove. It then updates `updatedRectWidth` and uses that to calculate the current desired scale.

```js
var controlPoint = document.getElementById("c");
var control = false;
var origRectWidth = 100;
var scale = document.getElementById("scale");
var relevantMouseMoveDist = 0;
var updatedRectWidth = origRectWidth;
var mouseDownPt = {};
var rotateDiv = document.getElementById("rotate");
var rotateString = rotateDiv.getAttribute('transform');
var rectangleAngle = parseInt(rotateString.slice(rotateString.indexOf("(") + 1)) * Math.PI / 180; // retrieve the angle from the DOM
var relevantMouseMoveDist;
var newMousePosn;
var oldMousePosn;

function resizeRightMiddle()
{
  updatedRectWidth += relevantMouseMoveDist;
  xScale = updatedRectWidth/origRectWidth;
  scale.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(' + xScale + ',1)');
}

var svg = document.getElementById("main");

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){

  if (newMousePosn) {
  
    // the former mouse pos'n
    oldMousePosn = {x: newMousePosn.x, y: newMousePosn.y};
    
    // the new mouse pos'n
    newMousePosn = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
    
    // the change in the mouse pos'n coordinates since the last move event
    var deltaMouseMove = {
      x: newMousePosn.x - oldMousePosn.x,
      y: newMousePosn.y - oldMousePosn.y
    };
    
    // the dir'n of this movement
    var angleOfMouseMovement = Math.atan2(deltaMouseMove.y, deltaMouseMove.x);
    
    // the absolute distance the mouse has moved
    var mouseMoveDist = Math.sqrt(
      deltaMouseMove.x * deltaMouseMove.x +
      deltaMouseMove.y * deltaMouseMove.y
    );
     
    // the difference in direction between the mouse movement and orientation of the rectangle
    var angleDifference = angleOfMouseMovement - rectangleAngle;
    
    // the portion of the mouse movement that is in the direction of the rectangle's orientation
    relevantMouseMoveDist = mouseMoveDist * Math.cos(angleDifference);
    
    // resize the rectangle if necessary
    if (control) resizeRightMiddle();
    
  } else {
  
    // establish the mouse pos'n during the first mousemove event
    newMousePosn = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
  }
  
});

svg         .addEventListener("mouseup"  , function(e){control = false;});
controlPoint.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){control = true ;});
```

```html
<div>
<svg id="main" width="1000" height="300">
 <g transform="translate(66, 56)">
  <g id="rotate" transform-origin="center" transform="rotate(40)">
   <g id="scale">
     <path fill="red" stroke="red" d="M 0 0 L 0 100 L 100 100 L 100 0Z" />
    <rect id="c" fill="black" stroke="black" x=95 y=45 width=10 height=10 />
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: hum thx again, I like the whole rebuild of the process unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue as a mouseY is not present. try with an angle of 90 degrees and you'll start feeling the real problem of the whole thing. Please let me know if you see what I mean.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It now (I believe) calculates the scaling correctly for any angle of the rectangle. I didn't use `getScreenCTM` and instead just recalculated the relevant proportion of the mouse movement using basic trigonometry, which can probably be done more elegantly using, e.g. `getScreenCTM` or something similar.

Comment: hum interesting ill have a look and tell you

Comment: Still perhaps not yet the most elegant, but I believe it is now working for any angle of the rectangle.

Comment: I've managed to make your code work in my implementation, thanks a lot.

Comment: I've just created a new post which is the continuation of this post. I would be really happy if you could answer this other question here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759344/how-can-i-make-my-n-resize-display-correctly). Thanks in advance